# Create empty object from a class (empty table for sql testing)

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a sql file which needs to be tested. There is a test.py available with a table as below:

```py
customers = InputTable(
    f_name.T1,
    SchemaDir.RECORDS,
    {
        'class' : ['A', 'B'],
        'startTimestamp': [
            utc_datetime(2020, 3, 1, 10, 0, 0),
            utc_datetime(2020, 3, 1, 10, 1, 0)
        ],
        'endTimestamp': [
            utc_datetime(2020, 3, 1, 10, 0, 0),
            utc_datetime(2020, 3, 1, 10, 1, 0)
        ],
        'desc': ['FAIL','PASS']
    },
    partition=dt.date(2020, 3, 1)
)
```

And the `InputTable` is defined in `utils.py` as:

```py
class InputTable:
    """
        A table containing source data
    """
    name: str
    schema_dir: str
    data: Union[Dict[str, List[Any]], Tuple[List[str], List[List[Any]]]]
    partition: date = None
```

So now I want to add another customers table which is empty. Then there will be lots of join and union with other tables. I defined empty customers table as below but the final query returns wrong result.

```py
customers_empty = InputTable(
    f_name.T1,
    SchemaDir.RECORDS,
    {
        'class': [],
        'startTimestamp': [],
        'endTimestamp': [],
        'desc': []
    }
)
```

I also have tried this as well:

```py
customers_empty = InputTable(f_name.T1, SchemaDir.RECORDS, {})
```

But both of them return wrong value. When I run the query manually in bigquery it return 2 rows as result but this test.py return 0 rows and I get this error: because I defined the output must be 2 rows * 5 columns.

```
DataFrame shape mismatch
E       [left]:  (0, 5)
E       [right]: (2, 5)
```

Is the customers_empty defined correctly? Because all my other tests are passing except the ones which use `customers_empty`.

Or use `None` or `Null` or `set()` somewhere?

`set()` does not work as it returns below error:

```py
customers_empty = InputTable(f_name.T1, SchemaDir.RECORDS, set())
```

`TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing`